# Who is responsible for xyz?

Tags: phrase-requests

If you ask:

*Who is responsible for xyz?*

.. some people feel threatened/attacked.

How to ask this basic question in a more friendly way?

Comment: You would get a better answer on [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you mean _responsible for_ in the sense of _guilty of doing  something wrong_, or _the person in charge of xyz_ ?

Comment: @KateBunting What is the difference between "guilty of doing" and "in charge of"?

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Do you mean "Who is responsible for breaking this window?", or "Who is responsible for managing this team?"

Comment: I think this question is based on a false premise. Just because *Who is responsible for **this mess**?* implies "condemnation" doesn't mean native speakers would assume the same applies to *Who is responsible for **managing this team**?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tone / state of relationship, and the nature of _xyz_, not the wording itself, are controlling factors.

Comment: The army cooks are responsible for *this* mess

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is why I asked the OP in which sense they meant it!

Comment: @KateBunting: That is why I upvoted *both* your comments at the same time as casting my VTC. The majority of closevoters apparently see "lack of information on how it will be used" as the basic problem. I will admit that aspect could be easily fixed, so actually *closevoting* might seem a bit harsh (though so far as I can see, the OP has either not understood or has ignored the request for more detail). But even if it *was* fixed, that wouldn't invalidate ***my*** reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the English language aspects of this, "responsible" does not itself have any negative connotations. It depends on the thing that someone is responsible for. If it is a negative thing, then there are negative connotations. If it is a positive thing then there are positive connotations.

For example:

> Who is responsible for this failure

Failure is a negative thing, the question has a negative connotation.

> Who is responsible for managing this team?

Managing the team is neither positive or negative of itself, so there is no positive or negative connotation. There might be implied positive or negative connotations if the team has been performing well or badly.

> Who is responsible for the million dollar sale?

A million dollar sale is a good thing. The question has positive connotations.

You should also note that "responsible" has positive connotations in other usages - someone who is "responsible" is someone who can be trusted with responsibility.

Comment: Very good point. Thank you very much.